# How use async/await with error reading sensor?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, async-await, raspberry-pi

Comment: I'm sure this is quite simple, but I can't seem to figure out the right combination of async/await try/catch.

Senario: I'm reading DHT22 temp/humidity sensor that may return an error, in which case I want to return a default value.  I want getHumidity() to wait for reading and return value or default value.  And then printConditions() simple calls and doesn't execute until it receives a response.

Question: Is it possible have delay in getHumidity(), and other calls are unaware its async, cause I have a lot of variations of printConditions()?

```
const printConditions = () => `Current Humidity is: ${getHumidity().fixed(2)}`;
//Both Attempts return: Current Humidity is NaN%
//Which I believe implies it is not waiting nor default value of 75.0.

//Attempt 1
const getHumidity = async () => {
try { return await sensor.read(22, sensorPin).humidity; }
catch (error) {console.log(error); return 75.0; }
}
```

try/catch block returns this error: ??? : (node:1368) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)

```
//Attempt 2:
const getHumidity = async () => {
return await sensor.read(22, sensorPin)
.then(value=>{ return value.humidity;})
.catch(error=>{console.log(error); return 75.0;});
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
const printConditions = async () => {
    let reading;
    try { 
        reading = await sensor.read(22, sensorPin).humidity;
    }
    catch(error) {
        console.log(error);
        reading = 75.0;
    }
    finally {
      console.log(`Current Humidity is: ${reading.fixed(2)}`);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

did you try adding an await when you call the asynchronus function?

```
const printConditions = async () => `Current Humidity is: ${await getHumidity().fixed(2)}`;
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, is there a way to only await getHumidity(), cause otherwise my entire call-tree would need to be async/await?   When the sensor doesn't throw an error, it works fine without async/await anywhere, even though it takes a few seconds to execute.